# tbody table returns empty list

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to webscrape a table from a webpage which has a `data_table` class. The data is within the `tbody` but when I use the xpath of the table it returns an empty list. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
link <- "https://www.mariokartcentral.com/mkc/registry/players"
page <- read_html(link)

page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="players_list"]/table/tbody') %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
#> list()
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Here is the element:

[image]

As you can see from the output it returns an empty list. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to web scrape a `tbody` element like above?

Comment: Common issue.  The data is populated after the page loads meaning you can't use `rvest` to scrape it.  In this case you can query the API directly - `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.mariokartcentral.com/mkc/api/registry/players/category/all?order=NA&country=ZZ&search=&ignore_filter=false&page=1")`.

Comment: a quick note regarding "can't use `rvest`":  last week version 1.0.4 was released to CRAN, latest version supports rendering and interactions with sites that use javascript though `chromote` (`rvest::read_html_live()`)